# MIT licence: can my application be uploaded in the iOS App Store?

Tags: software, licensing

I am developing an application that uses a library which has the MIT licence. As far as I understand, to use the library it's enough that I include a copy of the MIT licence in my software, and that the application is free.

But:

1. Am I allowed to upload the application in the App Store for free?
2. Am I obliged to make my software open source or I can keep my code secret?

**Edit**
MIT License

Copyright (c) [year] [fullname]

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.

Comment: Uh...The license doesn't really _interact_ with the app store policies though?  You might want to put a copy of the license in the question.

Comment: This may be better for Open Source Stackexchange. MIT license does not require that you open source your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am using a MIT licensed module in a closed source consumer device. What are my obligations?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/i-am-using-a-mit-licensed-module-in-a-closed-source-consumer-device-what-are-my). In that case it is a "device" but the situation is the same. You are releasing a product based on MIT licensed code, and you don't want to release your source code. Yes, the license says you can do that ("rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, ...") as long as you agree to the terms ("subject to the following conditions").

Comment: Have you read through these three paragraphs? Does it anywhere say you have you redistribute reticence any of your work under the same license? The license also clearly grants you rights concerning distribution etc.